# Backpropagation - Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, backpropagation, supervised-learning

How does the output value of step 1 result in the value of "0.582"?

I am looking at an example of the usage of backpropagation in order to have a basic understanding of it. However I fail to understand how the value "0.582" is formed as the output for the example below.

[image]

EDIT:

I have attempted Feed-Forward, which has resulted in having the output value of "0.5835...".

Now I am unsure if the example above output value is correct or whether the method I have used is correct.

EDIT2:

### My FF Calculation

> f(x) = 1/1+e^-x

.
>

> NodeJ = f( 1*W1j+0.4*W2j+0.7*W3j )
>
> NodeJ = f( 1(0.2)+0.4(0.3)+0.7(-0.1) ) = f(0.25)
>
> NodeJ = 1/(1+e^-0.25) = 0.562...

.

> NodeI = f( 1*W1i+0.4*W2i+0.7*W3i )
>
> NodeI = f( 1(0.1)+0.4(-0.1)+0.7(0.2) ) = f(0.25)
>
> NodeI = 1/(1+e^-0.25) = 0.562...

.

> NodeK = f( NodeJ * Wjk + NodeI * Wik)
>
> NodeK = f( 0.562(0.1)+0.562(0.5)) = f(0.3372)
>
> NodeK = 1/(1+e^-0.3372) = 0.5835
>
> Output = 0.5835

Comment: Show step-by-step how you plugged in the values please.

Comment: @kkm was able to update the original post with calculations

Comment: Your formulas look correct, but there is a calc error `NodeI`: 1(0.1)+0.4(-0.1)+0.7(0.2)  is 0.2, not 0.25.